# what happens to my npm private packages if i cancel my npm subscription?

Tags: npm

I'm considering paying an npm subscription to publish private packages and I'm wondering what would happen if I decided to cancel my subscription at some point. Would my private packages become public? Would they be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From NPM support staff in response to my ticket asking this same question:

> Hi there,
>
> If a private packages subscription is cancelled, the private packages
>   will remain under their org account, but unaccessible. If you need
>   access to the private packages in the future, you will need to
>   re-subscribe.
>
> If the owning account of the packages is deleted, all packages are
>   deleted.
>
> Please let us know if there is anything else we can do for you. We’ll
>   be here to help.
>
> Warmly, NPM Support

Comment: This needs to be on their FAQ